# How to call a specific function on a javascript file with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have file called `functionContainer.js` and in that file I have written

```
function returnTen(){
return 10;
}

function returnName(){
return "Stack Overflow";
}
```

and in `callAjax.js` file I need to call the `returnTen` function and get the data via an Ajax call.

(functionContainer.js is hosted in a server)

How can I do this?

Comment: you can write the returnTen function in the callAjax.js and when ajax completes then you can call this function in ...function(data){returnTen()}...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute **returnTen()**; after your ajax request finishes,
then put your **returnTen()** function inside of a **success, failure, or callback function**; whichever one you choose is up to you...

Here some example with ExtJs Ajaxcall :

Ext.Ajax.request({

```
url: 'page.php',

params: {
    id: 1
},
// scope: this,
```

// you can set the scope too

```
callback: function(opt,success,respon){

    **returnTen();**
}
```

});

Comment: I have updated the question. Now you have a clear idea what I exactly need to do.

Answer (score 0):

To make this method (**returnTen()**) callable from the client side script we need to make this static and decorate/adorn it with a WebMethod attribute.

The first thing that we need to do to be able to call the server side methods is to make the **EnablePageMethods="true" in the ScriptManager control.**

In Your script you can call server side js function like this:

function CallServerMethod()
{

```
// call the server side method here
PageMethods.returnTen();
```

}